# What happens to Elastic Network Interfaces after a AWS RDS instance is stopped temporarily ?

Tags: amazon-rds

While working on a project I have come across a scenario where my subnets are running out of IPs hence I decided to delete some of the Network interfaces which are in "Available" status. I have deleted all the available Network interfaces from AWS console. Later I realised that there are some RDS instances which were in stopped state are now being shown in "Incompatible Network" state. After digging into it more I found it is because of the Network interface deletion.

Could someone explain why stopping AWS RDS instances releases the network interfaces and put them in "Available" state unlike EC2 instances which keeps network interfaces in "In-use" state even after stopping the instance ? This prevents the network interfaces to be deleted accidentally.